# Не получается настроить FTP Сервер FileZilla

Tags: ftp, filezilla

Пытаюсь настроить FTP Сервер через FileZilla 0.9.31
Открыл в роутере порты 21,990,3000-4000
Настроил DDNS(No-Ip)
SSL Сертификаты в FileZilla отключил(может это важно)

При попытке подключение через локальную сеть на сервере отображается следующее:

```
Connected, sending welcome message...
(000005) 17.01.2022 14:45:18 - (not logged in) (192.168.1.160)> 220 Hello
(000005) 17.01.2022 14:45:18 - (not logged in) (192.168.1.160)> AUTH TLS
(000005) 17.01.2022 14:45:18 - (not logged in) (192.168.1.160)> 502 SSL/TLS authentication not allowed
(000005) 17.01.2022 14:45:18 - (not logged in) (192.168.1.160)> AUTH SSL
(000005) 17.01.2022 14:45:18 - (not logged in) (192.168.1.160)> 502 SSL/TLS authentication not allowed
(000005) 17.01.2022 14:45:18 - (not logged in) (192.168.1.160)> USER Maxim
(000005) 17.01.2022 14:45:18 - (not logged in) (192.168.1.160)> 331 Password required for maxim
(000005) 17.01.2022 14:45:18 - (not logged in) (192.168.1.160)> PASS ****
(000005) 17.01.2022 14:45:18 - maxim (192.168.1.160)> 230 Logged on
(000005) 17.01.2022 14:45:19 - maxim (192.168.1.160)> PWD
(000005) 17.01.2022 14:45:19 - maxim (192.168.1.160)> 257 "/" is current directory.
(000005) 17.01.2022 14:45:19 - maxim (192.168.1.160)> TYPE I
(000005) 17.01.2022 14:45:19 - maxim (192.168.1.160)> 200 Type set to I
(000005) 17.01.2022 14:45:19 - maxim (192.168.1.160)> PASV
(000005) 17.01.2022 14:45:19 - maxim (192.168.1.160)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (37,78,234,146,11,187)
(000005) 17.01.2022 14:45:19 - maxim (192.168.1.160)> MLSD
(000005) 17.01.2022 14:45:29 - maxim (192.168.1.160)> 425 Can't open data connection.
```

В клиенте отображается следующее:

```
Соединяюсь с 192.168.1.160:21...
Статус: Соединение установлено, ожидание приглашения...
Статус: Небезопасный сервер, не поддерживает FTP через TLS.
Статус: Авторизовались
Статус: Получение списка каталогов...
Команда:    PWD
Ответ:  257 "/" is current directory.
Команда:    TYPE I
Ответ:  200 Type set to I
Команда:    PASV
Ответ:  227 Entering Passive Mode (**,**,***,***,11,188) (Вместо звездочек здесь мой внешний IP)
Команда:    MLSD
Ошибка: Соединение передачи данных не может быть установлено: ECONNREFUSED - Соединение отклонено сервером
Ответ:  425 Can't open data connection.
Ошибка: Не удалось получить список каталогов
```

При попытке подключения не находясь в локальной сети(по внешнему ip или домену) сервер не видит попыток соеденения с ним, а в клиенте отображается слежующее:

```
Соединяюсь с **.**.***.***:21...
Статус: Не удалось установить соединение с "ECONNREFUSED - Соединение отклонено сервером".
Ошибка: Невозможно подключиться к серверу
```

Пробовал в консоли telnet 192.168.1.160 21 - подключение происходило и отображалось сообщение с сервера
Та же команда на внешний ip сбрасывала ошибку

Настройки в самом сервере следующие(3 скриншота ниже):

С чем это может быть связано и как пофиксить? Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: Очень частая ошибка, пробуйте пассивный режим, скорее всего закрыты дополнительные порты.

Comment: В пассивном режиме указаны открытые ранее порты 3000-4000 и внешний ip